# Select in tbl1 only if fields don't match in tbl2

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to select only the records from table "a" if a match is NOT found on two fields in table "b".  I have come up with the following, but it's simply returning all records.  The code seems simple enough, does Access not handle the SELECT 1 function properly or am I not using it right?  Thanks for any assistance.

```
SELECT a.[Part Number], 
       a.[Company Name], 
       a.[Customer Name], 
       a.[Customer Number], 
       a.[Salesperson Initials], 
       a.[Date Received], 
       a.Quantity, 
       a.ExtCost, 
       a.ExtPrice, 
       a.[Gross Margin]
FROM   [1: Orders in the period] As a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM [Price Adjustments New Gross Margin] As b 
              WHERE b.[Part Number]<>a.[Part Number] AND b.[Customer Name]<>a.[Customer Name]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN a` to `b` and return only those rows where the `b` side `Is Null`.

```
SELECT a.[Part Number], 
       a.[Company Name], 
       a.[Customer Name], 
       a.[Customer Number], 
       a.[Salesperson Initials], 
       a.[Date Received], 
       a.Quantity, 
       a.ExtCost, 
       a.ExtPrice, 
       a.[Gross Margin]
FROM
    [1: Orders in the period] AS a
    LEFT JOIN [Price Adjustments New Gross Margin] AS b 
    ON
            a.[Part Number]=b.[Part Number]
        AND a.[Customer Name]=b.[Customer Name]
WHERE b.[Part Number] Is Null;
```

If you prefer to stick with `EXISTS`, I think this may get what you want.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM [Price Adjustments New Gross Margin] AS b 
        WHERE
                b.[Part Number]=a.[Part Number]
            AND b.[Customer Name]=a.[Customer Name]
    );
```